# Using email instead of username in CakePHP's Auth Component

Tags: cakephp, authentication

CakePHP's Auth component requires the username field to be present in order to convert the password field into a hash upon save. Apparently, even if I put the following in the `beforeFilter()`:

```
$this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password');
```

it doesn't encrypt the password before inserting it into the database.

So my question is, assuming this is supposed to happen, what is the best way to encrypt the password? Or, have I made a simple error somewhere?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Here's the before filter in the users_controller.php:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password');
}
```

And the app_controller.php:

```
var $components = array('Auth');
```

Comment: Could you show some code. I.e. your beforeFilter function or even AppController class?

Comment: Oops, I had duplicated the line "$this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password');" in the AppController as well and it seems that was causing the problem. Sorry about that and thanks for the tip to double check by posting here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops, I had duplicated the line `$this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password');` in the `AppController` as well and it seems that was causing the problem. Sorry about that and thanks for the tip to double check by posting here :)